# Head First C# xaml designer column/row sizes 1*

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

This is minor but I'm trying to learn and am a complete novice.  I'm using VS 2015 instead of 2013 used in the book.

On page 73 of the 3rd edition the text (and pictures) indicate the the 2 columns and 3 rows should each be sized 1*.  I can't figure out a way to make this happen.

My steps are:  create a column in the design window, then mouseover the control area and click * on one of the columns/rows.  This sets the other to 1*.  Then clicking the other * locks it to another fixed value, neither with a * now.

Each column is by default showing a value with a * so my guess is this is a difference in the new IDE.

I'm trying to be sure that I'm not missing the point of automatic grid sizing.

Thank you.

Comment: * and 1* should be equivalent.

Comment: Thanks!  There's an example further on that I missed, of just using <RowDefinition/> with no parameters that seems to have the same effect.  I guess I picked the only way that didn't work!

Comment: As you get further in to WPF, I would recommend you try to edit the XAML directly, instead of using the designer.  Things are just less complicated that way, espceially the more advanced things. I originally learned with the designer like you, but now I hardly touch it, other than to get a visual preview of my changes

Comment: I appreciate your insight and will give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this manually by editing the `.xaml` content of your window.

Just use the below code instead of manually clicking on the columns:

```
<Grid>
    <ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

This is the code for a complete `Grid` so you have to remove the already existing grid.

Answer (score 1):

Star Sizing basically tells the grid to take all columns that are * sized and divide the remaining grid space (space not used by fixed width columns) up proportionally between them.  A column that is 2* will be twice as large as one that is 1* (or just *).

A single * is equivalent to 1* when using Star Sizing.